# Why are abstract methods not enforced in python virtual subclasses?

Tags: python, abstract

Python documentation states that abstract classes must be implemented by subclasses. It also states that you can create a "virtual subclass" by using the "register()" method (though super methods will not be callable by the subclass).

I would expect the following code to throw an error at `register()`, because io.FileIO does not have a "self_destruct" method.

```
import abc
import io

class MyFile(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def self_destruct(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

MyFile.register(io.FileIO)
```

but there is no error.

Is this a bug? Undocumented behavior? Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Relevant documentation page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Comment: The `abc` module doesn't do very much.  It's mostly for documentation.  Remember you always have the source code available to answer questions.

Comment: I feel like it would be better for 1 person to add documentation than for 7 million python developers to search through source code.

Comment: It would be pretty time-consuming to document what the class doesn't do.  And I very regularly go through the library modules to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

[`register`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e6eccabe8156d77d60ba532e60156bcd3592df1/Lib/_py_abc.py#L54) does not actually check to see if the abstract methods are implemented. Its implementation trusts that the programmer calling it knows what they are doing.